# CSS: Android browser not implementing font-size

Tags: android, css, font-size

I can't seem to get my font-size rule work in Android's default browser. And I've tried everything: 2 dozen of @media rules, HTML viewport tags, !important statements, what not. The Android browser simply just displays all the text in a fixed size. Other browsers work fine. What could be a reason for this?

Comment: What android version and devices have you tested on? Is the page public?

Comment: I need to apologize, soon after asking this I found the cause of the problem. Apparently Android's generic browser doesn't support CSS shorthend `font`. Instead I had to use `font-size`.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ I find that hard to believe to be honest. You may have had an error in the CSS syntax.

Comment: Mr Lister you can try it for yourself. `font` shorthend is detected in all browsers except Android's native. And maybe Chrome, haven't checked.